# Node.js, express: Process data in post, and send data to api

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a web app that takes data via user input, processes it in the server, and display the processed data back to the client.

My general workflow is as follow:

1. User uploads some data in the browser
2. Receive the data via POST method (using express)
3. Run internal data pipeline on the received data
4. Send the processed data to api
5. Client will use GET request to access the api

Currently, I am having a problem at step 4.

I tried to use nested router like this,

```
const express = require('express');

app = express();

// Simiulate data receiving from client
var getData = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("Data received!")
        }, 1000)
    })
}

// Simulated data pipeline 
var runPipeline = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("Some data")
        }, 1500)
    })
}

var sendDataToAPI = function (data) {
    // send data to "/api/data"
    console.log(data)
}

// get form data from client
// This was done using axios with React
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    // Get data
    // Process
    // Send it to API
    getData()
    .then(_ => runPipeline())
    .then(data => sendDataToAPI)
})
```

But it doesn't really work...

Any help or suggestions on alternative approaches would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## You can try async & await for that case

```
app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    // those block should be in another promise or await
    await GetData()
    await Process()

    // end it to API
    getData()
    .then(async _ => await runPipeline())
    .then(data => sendDataToAPI)
})
```